# Passing data from modal segue to parent

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to pass data (e.g. set var) from modal segue to parent, how can I do that?

I’m using that code to exit from modal segue:

```
@IBAction func doneClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I can’t use `segue.destinationViewController` here to pass data as i’m used to do on push segues.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create protocol on Modal ViewController

```
protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate
{
    func sendValue(var value : NSString)
}
```

Also declare in you Modal ViewController class

```
var delegate:ModalViewControllerDelegate!
```

Include this protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate in ParentViewController

When you are Moving form one viewController to another

```
 modalVC.delegate=self;
        self.presentViewController(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here you get your value in ParentViewcontroller

```
 func sendValue(value: NSString) {

    }
```

Finally on ModalViewController

```
@IBAction func doneClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
delegate?.sendValue("value")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: One nit, rather than "sendValue", I'd follow the apple delegate conventions and use something like `modalView:finishedWithValue:`  `sendValue` is still tying the caller and the receiver together more than is necessary.

Comment: Send you a link to what?  For the delegate conventions that Apple follows, just look at any of the modal view controllers they provide, `UIImagePickerController` for example.

Comment: Ohh I misunderstood I thought there is better way for call back implementation. You are right UIImagePickerController example is best. In fact in iOS we use a lot of call back it could be using delegate NSNotifcations, block, Selctor. This kind of problem can be done by anyone callback method. I like using delegate, protocol. I try to avoid using NSNotifications

Answer (score -1):

In the second viewController (the one showed by the segue) declare a variable like

```
var parentVC : UIViewController?
```

then when you call segue from parent

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegue" {
        let secondController= segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
secondController.parentVC = self
    }
}
```

so you can use

```
@IBAction func doneClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.parentVC.yourVariable = 0
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Really shouldn't be directly mucking about in other view controllers, that way lies madness.  You also gain a lot of flexibility if you don't make assumptions about the caller.  Far better to follow the standard model set by `UIKit` and use a delegate and/or callback on completion.  See [Shashi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28503148/3203487).