# IOS modal view from main UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, unwind-segue

I am using a segue to present a modal view of a UIViewController that has the same (UIViewController) swift class. In the modal I present a UITextField to capture some user input; Then when I then unwind the segue on the modal to return to the original view, the value is removed from the UITextfield, so I am thinking I am not implementing this correctly (newer swift/xcode developer here).

My question is should I be creating a separate class to attach to each modal view every time, and pass that data back to the originating view controller in the unwind segue? Is there another way to provide a modal UI to the user using the same view controller class context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, create a separate class for your modal view, and pass the data back. Use a protocol!

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502653/passing-data-from-modal-segue-to-parent) addresses your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping to not have to create a class for each modal view (have about 25  modals to do), but it seems that is the only/best way.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote *^^* Hopefully you can repurpose one view controller in different modals~