# How to pass data from modal view controller back when dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502653/passing-data-from-modal-segue-to-parent) but I'm still unsure about this part:

```
modalVC.delegate=self;
self.presentViewController(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I've tried instantiating the view controller programmatically but still to no avail.

here's my code for when dismissing the modal view controller:

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
        //
    }
}
```

I'm using storyboard to segue with modal view.

This is the data I wish to transfer back to the parent view controller:

```
var typeState = "top"
var categoryState = "casual"
```

Which are two String values.

I've tried to pass data from the modal view controller as shown:

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.sendValue(value: "success")
    if let presenter = presentingViewController as? OOTDListViewController {
        presenter.receivedValue = "test"
    }
}
```

whereas on the parent view controller I did as such:

```
func sendValue(value: NSString) {
    receivedValue = value as String
}

@IBAction func printReceivedValue(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(receivedValue)
}
```

I still couldnt receive any value when I hit the print button.

Modal view controller:

```
protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate
{
    func sendData(typeState: String, categoryState: String)
}

var delegate:ModalViewControllerDelegate!

var typeState = "top"
var categoryState = "casual"
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.sendData(typeState: typeState as String, categoryState: categoryState as String)
}
```

Parent view controller:

```
class parentViewController: UICollectionViewController, ModalViewControllerDelegate {

var typeState: String?
var categoryState: String?

func sendData(typeState: String, categoryState: String) {
    self.typeState = typeState as String
    self.categoryState = categoryState as String
}

@IBAction func printReceivedValue(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(typeState)
}
```

Here's my new code without using delegate method:

Modal view Controller:

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let presenter = presentingViewController as? OOTDListViewController {
        presenter.typeState = typeState
        presenter.categoryState = categoryState
    }
}
```

OOTDListViewController:

```
@IBAction func presentModalView(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let modalView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filterViewController") as! ModalViewController
    let navModalView: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: modalView)
    self.present(navModalView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func printValue(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(typeState)
    print(categoryState)
}
```

Comment: Are you presenting the viewcontroller with a segue or in code?

Comment: I'm presenting the modal view with storyboard segue

Comment: printing still returned nil or a blank answer

Comment: You need to set the values **before** dismissing the viewController, otherwise the presentingViewController will always be nil. So, move the `self.dismiss` call at the end of the `dismissViewController` function.

Comment: still doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with me initiating a navigation controller hierarchy?

Comment: No, this shouldn't interfere. Did you put a breakpoint on `if let presenter = presentingViewController as? OOTDListViewController` to see if the check fails or not? As I said in my answer, if the `OOTDListViewController` is part of a navigation stack, you may need to look for it in the `viewControllers` property of the root navigation controller.

Comment: Yup I've tried the breakpoint. if let presenter = presentingViewController as? OOTDListViewController wasnt called. I even add a print("sucess") if that method was called but it wasnt

Edit: yeah I have to find a way to ditch the navigation controller hierarchy

Comment: Your test works! But I really have no idea why mine doesnt :/ I see the exact same code here. I guess I'm gonna role with NS user defaults for that selection. But still, thanks a lot. It'll be really helpful for those who wish to transfer data to their parent view controller without using delegate methods

Comment: Updated sample project with a delegate approach, maybe it will help: https://github.com/smeshko/ModalDataPassing

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Depending on the data you want to pass, you can create a property in the presenting view controller, which you can set when dismissing the modal view controller, so you can spare yourself the delegate.

For example, you have a `ContactsViewController`, holding a `var contacts: [Contact] = []` property. When you want to create a new contact, you present a modal view controller with the different values you need to create a new `Contact` object. When you are done and want to dismiss the view controller,  you call the function as you did in your code, but set the property in the `ContactsViewController`. It will look something like this:

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let presenter = presentingViewController as? ContactsViewController {
        presenter.contacts.append(newContact)
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

If you **don't** want to use a delegate, this is how you go about it:

In your `OOTDListViewController` :

```
var testValue: String = ""

@IBAction func printReceivedValue(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(testValue)
}
```

In your modal view controller (I'll call it `PresentedViewController`) :

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // if your OOTDListViewController is part of a UINavigationController stack, this check will probably fail. 
    // you need to put a breakpoint here and check if the presentingViewController is actually a UINavigationController.
    // in that case, you will need to access the viewControllers variable and find your OOTDListViewController
    if let presenter = presentingViewController as? OOTDListViewController {
        presenter.testValue = "Test"
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If you **want** to use a delegate, this is how to do it:

In your OOTDListViewController:

```
protocol ModalDelegate {
    func changeValue(value: String)
}
    
class OOTDListViewController: ModalDelegate {

    var testValue: String = ""
    @IBAction func presentViewController() {
        // here, you either create a new instance of the ViewController by initializing it, or you instantiate it using a storyboard. 
        // for simplicity, I'll use the first way
        // in any case, you cannot use a storyboard segue directly, bevause you need access to the reference of the presentedViewController object
        let presentedVC = PresentedViewController() 
        presentedVC.delegate = self
        present(presentedVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func changeValue(value: String) {
         testValue = value
         print(testValue)
    }
}
```

In your `PresentedViewController`:

```
class PresentedViewController {
    var delegate: ModalDelegate? 
    var testValue: String = ""

    @IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       if let delegate = self.delegate {
            delegate.changeValue(testValue)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I really dont get how the value can be passed back to the parent view controller. 

they said to use the method of creating a protocol on the modal view and then create a function to that will receive that value in the parent view controller. I did all that except the part which I highlighted and couldn't get any data.

Comment: I used the non delegate method and I instantiated everything by code. But I needed the navigation bar if not there will be no top bar to allow me to have a done button. I have updated my post with the current code I'm using.

Comment: Which is the 'preferred' method to do this? using delegate or not using delegate!?

Comment: This method of not using the delegate was SOOOO helpful! As was the comment about what to do if the initial VC was embedded in a navigation controller. Posting my code below.

Comment: I would always use a delegate here. Using the presentingViewController in the presentedViewController in such a way is making both VCs highly dependent on one another. If you decided to present the view controller from a different one, your dismiss functionality will be broken and you wont be able to pass your data back.

Comment: I agree with @FOMDDeveloper, delegate method make everything clear, you need to pass pass delegate to presented vc from presenting vc and you call the delegate method in presented vc, no hidden tricks and less coupling.

Answer (score 5):

If using a navigation controller you will have to first grab the UINavigation Controller and then get the correct ViewController from the Navigation Controller stack.

Here's how my code looked in that case.

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let navController = presentingViewController as? UINavigationController {
       let presenter = navController.topViewController as! OOTDListViewController
        presenter.testValue = "Test"
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This worked for me with a top level Navigation Controller

Answer (score 3):

I am using the a tab bar so the working code is as below:

```
if let tabBar = self.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController {
    let homeNavigationViewController = tabBar.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController
    let homeViewController = homeNavigationViewController?.topViewController as! HomeController
    homeViewController._transferedLocationID = self.editingLocationID!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the delegate method in `dismissViewController` method

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    delegate?.sendData(typeState: "top", categoryState: "casual")
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
        //
    }
 }
```

in you Modal ViewController class create delegate

```
weak var delegate: MyProtocol?
```

create a protocol with the method name sendData in MyProtocol and in your presentingViewController where you are assigning the delegate, implement the MyProtocol method

```
protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {
    func sendData(typeState: String, categoryState: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    var typeState: String?
    var categoryState: String?

    override func viewDidApear() {
        super.viewDidApear()
        presentNewModalVC()
    }
    
    func presentNewModalVC() {
       let modalVC = NewModalViewControllerToBePresented()
       modalVC.delegate = self
       present(modalVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    func sendData(typeState: String, categoryState: String) {
       self.typeState = typeState
       self.categoryState = categoryState
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nope still not working. Just to clarify, the protocol is supposed to be created in the modal view controller swift file right? 

Could it be because I used storyboard segue to present the modal view controller and that's why its not working?

Comment: the protocol  should be created seperate of the modal or presented class. follow the given answer

Comment: you were missing the `vc.delegate = self` from ViewController before presenting the viewController