# unwindSegue could not pass data (Swift - Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, segue, nsuserdefaults

I'm using UserDefaults to store and retrieve my data but I have no idea why when I perform an unwind segue, my userdefaults data could not be passed over to the next view controller but if i do a normal push segue, my userdefaults data could be seen in the next viewcontroller.

P.S: ONLY `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegue", sender: nil)` is the unwindSegue.

FirstViewController

```
@IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
    var i: Int = 0
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
    i = Int(randomNumber)

    let alert = AlertController(title: "Congratualations", message: "You earned \(i) tokens!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.setTitleImage(UIImage(named: "token"))
    // Add actions
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Let's See!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                var returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tokens")
                returnValue = returnValue + i;
                UserDefaults.standard.set(returnValue, forKey:"tokens")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegue", sender: nil)
                }))
        if (returnValue != 30){
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue Playing", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:    { (action) in
                var returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tokens")
                returnValue = returnValue + i;
                UserDefaults.standard.set(returnValue, forKey:"tokens")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "continue", sender: self)
                }))
        }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit

class TokenController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tokens: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var minus1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var minus2: UIButton!
    var returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tokens")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tokens.text = "x\(returnValue)"
    }

@IBAction func unwindSegue(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `vuewDidLosd` will not fire for an unwind segue since you are returning to a view controller that is already loaded. Use `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Kinja you can refer below url i have answered

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do a Push of a new ViewController, this is loaded into memory and it's method "ViewDidLoad" is called. 
When you do an unwind segue , the previous ViewController is already in memory, so the viewDidLoad and all the initialization are not called and the labels and all the graphics are not updated.
This is not a problem, because you can access all the data you needed in the unwindSegue implementation through the variable sender. See this example:

```
func unwindToViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let vc_source = segue.source as! SecondViewController
        self.myLabel.text! = vc_sorgente.myTextField.text!      
}
```

Comment: Ok i tried using ur method but apparently it doesn't segue to my 2nd view controller afterwards. This is my code: https://ibb.co/chSs8m

Comment: check why returnValue is nil. I don't have all your code so I can't see the definition of that variable in the PickCardController and I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: its ok i manage to solve the found nil while unwrapping an optional value, i just change my label var from "UILabel!" to "UILabel?

Comment: but the strange thing is, it seems that i have to load my 2nd viewcontroller(which is the token page) first before it can actually pass the data from my 1st viewcontroller to my 2nd viewcontroller

Comment: I think I don't understand the sequence of your VCs. The sequence is :

PickCardController -> TokenController -> PickCardController 

or

TokenController -> PickCardController -> TokenController?

Comment: It's just PickCardController -> TokenController. but i think the reason why i got the fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value is because i haven't load my UILabel from my TokenController which is why i just perform an unwindsegue

Comment: You shouldn't use an unwind segue in this case....
You should use an unwind segue if after loaded the TokenController you want to come back to the PickCardController passing some data to it.

Comment: ok if thats the case may i know how can i segue from PickCardController -> TokenController while still having the tab bar in TokenController visible? because TokenController is part of a tab in my TabController

Answer (score -1):

@Kinja Please refer this url to use unwind segue

> Click here:-  [Perform action when segue is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060720/perform-action-when-segue-is-closed/48061222#48061222)

Comment: Ok i tried using ur method but apparently it doesn't segue to my 2nd view controller afterwards. This is my code: https://ibb.co/chSs8m

Comment: ok i managed to resolve it but smith strange happen. it seems that i have load my 2nd viewcontroller(which is the token page) first before it can actually pass the data from my 1st viewcontroller to my 2nd viewcontroller

Comment: and oh if u're wondering how i manage to solve the found nil while unwrapping an optional value, i just change my label var from "UILabel!" to "UILabel?"

Comment: can you please explain more i am not getting