# Protocol function sends the value back to the first VC but does not set it to the variables

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning IOS, and I have three view controllers A, B and C, and I can access C from B and B from A, then I send back data using this [delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126662/how-to-pass-data-from-modal-view-controller-back-when-dismissed) from C to A then I want to use these received data in A, and finally update the text in the textView of VC A, but it always updates the textView using the default values not the received ones.

**class A**

```
protocol isAbleToReceiveData{
    func pass(book: String, chapter: Int)
}

class AViewController: UIViewController, isAbleToReceiveData{

    var verses: [DBTVerse] = []
    var text: String = ""
    var currentBook: String = "Test"
    var currentChapter: Int = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var TextView: UITextView!

    func pass(book: String, chapter: Int) {
        self.currentBook = book
        self.currentChapter = chapter
        print(currentBook, currentChapter)
        // current output is ok "the received data"
        }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        getVerses(book: self.currentBook, Chapter: NSNumber(value: self.currentChapter))

        print(currentBook, currentChapter)
        // current output "test" "1" while it should be the received data
    }

    func data(verses: [DBTVerse]) {
        for verse in verses{
            if let chapter: Int = verse.verseId?.intValue{
            text.append(String(chapter))
            text.append(verse.verseText)
            }
        }
        updateData(text: text)
    }

    func updateData(text: String){
        if let textView = self.versesTextView {
        textView.text = text
        textView.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }    

    func getVerses(book: String, Chapter: NSNumber) {
        DBT.getTextVerse(withDamId: "ARBWTCO1ET", book: book, chapter: Chapter, verseStart: nil, verseEnd: nil, success: { (verse) in
            if let verse = verse {
                    self.verses = verse as! [DBTVerse]
                    self.data(verses: self.verses)
            }
        }) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**class C**

```
class CTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var currentBook: String = ""
    var chapters: [DBTChapter] = []
    var AVC = AViewController()
    var delegate: isAbleToReceiveData?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = AVC
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let selectedChapter = Int(chapters[indexPath.row].chapterId) {
            doDismiss(book: currentBook, chapter: selectedChapter)
        }
    }

    func doDismiss(book: String, chapter: Int) {
        if let delegate = self.delegate{
            delegate.pass(book: book, chapter: chapter)
        }
        // Use presentingViewController twice to go back two levels and call
        // dismissViewController to dismiss both viewControllers.
        self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So in general A receives the data but it does not override it to the variable so I can use it later or in the viewWillAppear.

Comment: how are you presnet those viewcontroller, your navigation flow, i guess from a you us do a present or a segue to nextViewController and set the delagate what i saw in you code you create an instance of a class to be the delegate and thats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell to next Viewcontroller who is it delegate like so if you are in A VC ande B goes trhow a segue then add in A viewController

```
class AViewController: UIViewController, isAbleToReceiveData{
   //all class details
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToClassB"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! bViewController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

in class B then you have a new property like c with

```
class b: UIVIewcontroller{
var delegate: isAbleToReceiveData?
```

So in the func to segue to next viewController c VC add this func

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToClassC"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! CTableViewController
        vc.delegate = self.delegate
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh many thanks!, I have tried this before too but in Class B I made it vc.delegate = self as? isAbleToReceiveData instead of what you did, and I guess this was the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem man, some time is not clear how delegates work when and that kind of problems happens